# insert value procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, insert, procedure

I'm new to PL/SQL.i need a procedure that insert value . i created QABZ table
[table QABZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NPru.png)

i wrote a procedure that insert value into my table but does'nt work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertQABZ(
       P_QNUM IN QABZ.QBZ_NUM%TYPE,
       p_QS IN QABZ.QBZ_SERIAL%TYPE,
       p_QD IN QABZ.QBZ_DATE%TYPE,
       p_QC IN QABZ.VCODE%TYPE
       p_PNUM IN QABZ.POLICE_NUM%TYPE,
       p_CR IN QABZ.CERTI_NUM%TYPE,
       p_PLK IN QABZ.PELAK%TYPE,
       p_p IN QABZ.QBZ.PLACE%TYPE)
      )
    IS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO QABZ ("QBZ_NUM", "QBZ_SERIAL", "QBZ_DATE", "VCODE",,"POLICE_NUM","CERTI_NUM","PELAK","PLACE") 
            VALUES (p_QNUM ,p_QS ,p_QD ,p_QC,p_PNUM ,p_CR ,p_PLK,p_p);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Maybe you have an error in `p_p IN QABZ.QBZ.PLACE%TYPE`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please define "doesn't work" in a bit more detail.

Comment: yes thanks the error was in ```QABZ.QBZ.PLACE%TYPE ```